# What is APNS Device Token composed of?

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications, devicetoken

What is the device token received in `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` composed of?

This device token is used to uniquely identify an application when pushing notifications from server. But my query is as to what this device token is made up of?

Comment: from hex, what is the point of question?

Comment: Its an alpha-numeric string that APNS creates to uniquely identify your device.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoting from apple docs

**What is Device Token**

> A device token is an opaque NSData instance that contains a unique
>   identifier assigned by Apple to a specific app on a specific device.
>   Only APNs can decode and read the contents of a device token. Each app
>   instance receives its unique device token when it registers with APNs

**How its Generated**

> When a new device token is needed, APNs generates one using
>   information contained in the device’s certificate. It encrypts the
>   token using a token key and returns it to the device, as shown in the
>   middle, right-pointing arrow.

For more detail read :
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/APNSOverview.html

I could write whole theory but then it would be repetition of doc :)